# How to keep numbers in place whilst printing them

Tags: c++

How do I keep numbers in place without making a new line?, like a timer for example: https://www.timeanddate.com/timer/

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

void sleepcp(int milliseconds) 
{
    clock_t time_end;
    time_end = clock() + milliseconds * CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000;
    while (clock() < time_end)
    {
    }
}

int main() {
    int i = 0;
    while(i < 20) {
        i++;
        cout << "Time:" << i;
        sleepcp(1000);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You will want to include `iomanip` and make use of [std::setw](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw) to ensure you are working with fixed-width output. Otherwise see the ANSI escape for *clear to end of line*.

Answer (score 2):

printing out this console code `"\033[1A"` will move the cursor up one line then you reprint your string. So this should work.

```
#define CL_ERASE        "\033[2K"
#define CL_RESET        "\033[0m"
#define CL_MOVEUP       "\033[1A"

cout << CL_ERASE << CL_MOVEUP "Time:" << i << CL_RESET;
```

Here are some more console colors you just have to add CL_RESET to the end of your color string to make the text reset to default terminal color.

```
#define CL_RESET        "\033[0m"
#define CL_BOLD         "\033[1m"
#define FG_BLUE         "\033[34m"
#define FG_RED          "\033[31m"
#define FG_PURPLE       "\033[35m"
#define FG_LIGHTBLUE    "\033[94m"
#define FG_LIGHTRED     "\033[91m"
#define FG_LIGHTGREEN   "\033[92m"
#define FG_YELLOW       "\033[93m"
#define FG_LIGHTGREY    "\033[37m"
#define FG_ORANGE       "\x1b[38;5;172m"
```

Comment: Both answers will also want `\033[0K` (clear to end of line) to handle the removal of characters such as when the hour changes from `12` to `1`, etc... You may also want `\033[?25l` (hide cursor) and `\033[?25h` (restore cursor). It should also be mentioned that ANSI escapes are generally limited to VT compatible terminals (most are).

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is the carriage return symbol `\r`. Like `\n`, it is a special character that controls the position of the cursor. You will also need to flush the `cout` buffer every time to obtain a fluid visual timer:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

void sleepcp(int milliseconds) 
{
    clock_t time_end;
    time_end = clock() + milliseconds * CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000;
    while (clock() < time_end)
    {
    }
}

int main() {
    int i = 0;
    while(i < 20) {
        i++;
        cout << '\r' << "Time:" << i;
        cout.flush();
        sleepcp(1000);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Remember that when you write to `cout`, the text is buffered and it is not sent to the actual screen immediately. You may have noticed that when you use `std::endl` to break the line it always automatically outputs to `cout`. This is because `std::endl` adds a new line equivalent to the `\n` character and **also** flushes the stream. `\r` does not flush, which is why I added the flush line after writing to the output.

Comment: You will also want to look at *clear to end of line* and *hide cursor* and *restore cursor*. See suggestions below other answer.